# How can I use doOnTextChanged() without overriding textWatcher?

Tags: android, kotlin, default

I am not familiar with hints of Kotlin or Java in [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio). Most of them confuse me as a beginner to Android. For example, what does the following mean?

```
doOnTextChanged(CharSequence, Int, Int, Int)
```

I know that in overriding method `(s:CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int)`, the first one is a variable that stores the current text of `textView`. But how can I use it here without overriding? The second is `start`, third is `before`, and the last is `count` in the overriding method. But I just know the role of `s: CharSequence` and don't know how to use other three stuffs in overriding method.

Is there a ***book*** that explains these elementary concepts very easy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without Kotlin, you would have to create a class that implements TextWatcher and override the `onTextChanged()` function to be able to react to the text as it changes.

With Kotlin, Android Jetpack provides a convenience TextView extension function with the `doOnTextChanged` which allows you to simply react to the TextView's text changes with a lambda function.

Without the Kotlin extension function, you would react to text changes by doing this:

```
myTextView.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {} // do nothing
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {} // do nothing

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int)  {
        // This function is called each time text in the text view is changed
        // s is the current text. The other parameters tell you which characters are
        // changed since the last time the function was called.

        // Put code in here that you want to run each time there's a change.
    }
})
```

With the Kotlin extension function, it is more concise because you don't have to write out the extra functions you aren't using:

```
myTextView.doOnTextChanged { s, start, before, count ->
    // The code in this lambda function is called each time text in the text view is changed
}
```

The Kotlin documentation is not very useful to a complete beginner. It is written as if you are already familiar with at least one object-oriented language. The Java documentation is much more beginner-friendly. Although the syntax is different, the teaching about the basic object-oriented concepts is very helpful to someone new to Kotlin and object-oriented programming. [You can start here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) The concept being used here is **Interfaces**.

Java doesn't have extension functions. That is a Kotlin feature that allows functions to be written for classes without overriding anything. In this case, the Jetpack authors use this feature to provide more concise syntax for Kotlin users by using features that could not be implemented in Java 7 (the version of Java Android uses for its standard library of code). If Android had been written with Java 8 or later, TextWatcher could have default empty implementations for the two less-frequently used functions, which would have eliminated the need for this Kotlin extension function to provide concise syntax.

Note that if you look at the source code for this extension function, it is actually still overriding TextWatcher. It's just doing it on your behalf under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for valuable post. one of  my problems as I said in post is that I don't know what `s, start, before, count ->` are to use them or enter as input in Kotlin extension function!

Comment: You should look at the documentation for the associated TextWatcher function to find out what they do. Jetpack's extension functions are really lacking in clear documentation. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int) When you aren't sure, you can Ctrl+click a function in Android Studio  to jump to its source code. In this case, it would show you that it's using TextWatcher, so you could click through to the TextWatcher documentation to find out what it's doing.

Comment: Sorry for another comment. Thanks for `Ctrl`+click. When I print `text, start, before, count` from `myTextView.doOnTextChanged { s, start, before, count ` I get text of textview, number of characters entered minus 1 (started from 0) but it is weird a little that `before` is 0 if `count` is 1 and it is 1 if `count` is 0. Why? Your provided url didn't helped.

Comment: Hey @Tenfour04 how are you? Sorry I am asking my question to another question post. Can you help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73986681/11560810). Thanks

Comment: HI @vivekmodi, sorry, I have zero experience with Bluetooth specifications. I don't know what any of it means.

Comment: @Tenfour04: Sorry for comment. See my answer to this post below to see my problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Other ways to do it

Use this dependency in Gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:latest_version'
```

You can simply use the below code.

```
edit_text.addTextChangedListener { it: Editable? ->
  // Do your stuff here
}
```

Or

```
edit_text.doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after -> // Do stuff }
```

The explanation:

This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count of characters beginning at the start have just replaced old text that had length before. It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from this callback.

For your reference:

*[TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)*

Comment: What "s"? E.g., in *"within s"*.

Comment: OK, it may refer to the question's `(s:CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int)`.

Answer (score 0):

As I tried to print all parameters out using `Toast`, it is weird a little that the parameter `after` is 0 if count is 1 and it is 1 if count is 0. (no matter where the cursor is, middle of text or end of text!)

```
Toast.makeText(this,
"Char Sequence= $s and+ start= $start and+ before= $before and+ count= $count"
,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

[image]

So

`s`= all characters of the text that is currently changing

`start` = position of cursor