# what is the difference between doOnTextChanged and addTextChangedListener in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

what is the difference between myEditText.doOnTextChanged{} and myEditText.addTextChangedListener{} when programming android apps in kotlin.  Why use on over the other and when?

Comment: A very good explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73978429/3290339).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These questions are best answered looking at the actual implementation.

`addTextChangedListener` is an extension function on `TextView` that accepts a `beforeTextChanged`, and `afterTextChanged` and an `onTextChanged` lambdas, then creates a `TextWatcher` to add to the textview, using those lambdas for the callbacks:

```
public inline fun TextView.addTextChangedListener(
    crossinline beforeTextChanged: (
        text: CharSequence?,
        start: Int,
        count: Int,
        after: Int
    ) -> Unit = { _, _, _, _ -> },
    crossinline onTextChanged: (
        text: CharSequence?,
        start: Int,
        before: Int,
        count: Int
    ) -> Unit = { _, _, _, _ -> },
    crossinline afterTextChanged: (text: Editable?) -> Unit = {}
): TextWatcher {
    val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            afterTextChanged.invoke(s)
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(text: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            beforeTextChanged.invoke(text, start, count, after)
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(text: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            onTextChanged.invoke(text, start, before, count)
        }
    }
    addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)

    return textWatcher
}
```

`doAfterTextChanged` simply calls `addTextChangedListener` providing only the `onTextChanged` lambda, letting the `beforeTextChanged`  and `afterTextChanged` lambdas fallback to the default, no-op implementation:

```
public inline fun TextView.doAfterTextChanged(
    crossinline action: (text: Editable?) -> Unit
): TextWatcher = addTextChangedListener(afterTextChanged = action)
```